# Please tell this newbie what the difference is between these two list outputs?

Tags: python, django, list, python-2.7

I am struggling with something and have tracked it down to the difference between two lists inside my code: from the Python Debugger:

```
(Pdb) Values
['Thing1', 'Thing2', 'Thing3']
(Pdb) values2
[['Thing1', 'Thing2', 'Thing3']]
```

I *do NOT* want the double brackets, what does this mean and how do I get rid of them?

```
'Values' creation was by:
values = ['Thing1','Thing2','Thing3']
```

'Values2' creation was by:

```
for report in Report.objects.filter(id=id):
        values2.append([str(report.name), str(report.subject), str(report.description)])
```

Why am I getting this difference and how can I get Values2 to look like Values ?

Comment: `Values` is a `list` with 3 `str` in it, while `values2` is a `list` with one `list` inside of it, and the inner list has three `str` objects in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think of it as "double brackets".  Think of it as two sets of single brackets, one inside the other.  A set of brackets means you have a list.  Two sets of single brackets means you have two lists.  One set of single brackets inside another means you have a list inside another list.

This is because the value you appended was a list, because you did `values2.append([...])`.  The `[...]` is a list, so you appended a list; that is, you put a nested list inside `values2`.

If you don't want that, you could do:

```
values2.extend([str(report.name), str(report.subject), str(report.description)])
```

`extend` will add each element of the list as a separate element, instead of adding the whole list as one element.  (Whether this will actually work in the larger context of your program depends on what you actually do with `values2`.)

Comment: I suspect in this case they really do want a list of lists (or tuples), they just don't know it yet.

Answer (score 1):

`values2` is a list with a single element that is a list.

You are appending a list to a list. What you want to do is ***extend*** the `values2` list:

```
for report in Report.objects.filter(id=id):
    values2.extend([str(report.name), str(report.subject), str(report.description)])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your loop

```
for report in Report.objects.filter(id=id):
    values2.append( [ str(report.name), str(report.subject), str(report.description) ] )
```

you can see that what you are *appending* to `values2` is the the list

```
[ str(report.name), str(report.subject), str(report.description) ]
```

so `values2` - assuming it was empty in the first place - now has *one* element, being that list, and it looks like

```
[
    ['Thing1', 'Thing2', 'Thing3'],
]
```

as you described.

If you want to append the three *strings* instead then you have to do it one at a time, like this

```
for report in Report.objects.filter(id=id):
    values2.append(str(report.name))
    values2.append(str(report.subject))
    values2.append(str(report.description))
```

or you could use `extend` instead, but I believe that would be less clear.

Comment: There's more noise in the single `extend` call and it's unnecessarily long. Aligning the matching characters in the three `append` calls makes it very obvious that it's doing the same thing to three diffrent attributes of the same object. It's far from clear-cut, which is why I wrote *"I believe that would be less clear"*

Comment: Sorry, this instantly solved my last problem of the day, extend worked just fine, marking this one done!